# What characters that are converted when running PHP on IIS?

Tags: php, iis

I was reading this article about file upload vulnerability: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

I saw this statement:

> Finding characters that are converted to other useful characters
>   during the file upload process. For instance, when running PHP on IIS,
>   the ">", "<", and double quote " characters respectively convert to
>   "?", "*", and "." characters that can be used to replace existing
>   files (e.g. "web<<" can replace the "web.config" file). In order to
>   include the double quote character in the filename in a normal file
>   upload request, the filename in the "Content-Disposition" header
>   should use single quotes (e.g. filename='web"config' to replace the
>   "web.config" file).

1. Can anyone explain it to me with an example? how "web<<" will replace "web.config" and other files?
2. and the second part about "Content-Disposition"?

Comment: For question 1, here's a hint: angle brackets are not allowed inside file names in Windows and in many programs they're used as IO redirection operators. Note that if a server is configured correctly then the web-application will not be allowed to delete or overwrite its own `web.config` file anyway.

Comment: @Dai That is not true, actually. I can easily create a file called "t>1" for example using a simple `touch t\>1`. It is a question of how the command interpreter (typically the shell) handles commands, not what is "not allowed" by the operating system.

Comment: I would be _very_ wary on any system that "converts" input character silently in background, actually. That is not a good idea in the first place. It sounds as if the old mistake done with the `magic_quotes` in php is done all over again.

Comment: @arkascha `touch` is not a command on Windows. Linux specifically allows any character except `/` and `\0` (NULL) to exist in a file or directory name. NTFS specifically does not allow angle-brackets, see here: http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf

Comment: thanks guys , but still my question not answered .